# Angular 2 listen to custom event inside component

Tags: angular, event-handling

What I intend to do is to create a custom event to which I'll listen inside the same component that is created;

**events.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
    moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist/", "/"),
    selector: 'event-bind-c',
    template:`
             <button (click)="onClicked()">Component click</button>
             <input (clicked)="showIt($event)" [placeholder]="emitted_val">
            `
})
export class EventBindingComponent implements OnInit {
    toggled_value:boolean = false;
    emitted_val:string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<string>();
    onClicked = () => {
        //alert("Inside of component");
        this.clicked.emit("It works!");
    }

    showIt = (event_val:string) => {
        alert("event_val:" + event_val);
        this.emitted_val = event_val;
    }
}
```

If I use it outside of the component(in parent) it works

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<event-bind-c (clicked) = "onParentClicked($event)"></event-bind-c>',
})
export class AppComponent  { 
 onParentClicked= (value:string) => {
   alert("Outside of component "+value);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not supported.

Only the parent component can bind to an event emitted by an `@Output()`

Why don't you just call `this.showIt()` instead of emitting an event?

Comment: I was going through a tutorial and just wondering if I need to listen to a custom event inside the same component how would I do that. I couldn't find on the internet.

Comment: As I said, it's not supported. If you mean DOM events, then you bind the same way as to events from outputs.